# Get list of categories with full path

Tags: php, href

Currently I got a code which displays list of categories. I was able to make a single subcategory but i want to make it infinite like category/sub-category/sub-sub-category/etc/article. Structure of categories database is id, title, slug parent_id which by default is 0.

I've tried to loop the query but kinda don't know how to do it in a proper way, it just didn't worked.

Function look as:

```
    public static function getCategoryList()
    {

        $db = Db::getConnection();

        $lang = self::Language();

        $categoryList = [];

        $result = $db->query("SELECT content.id, content.title$lang,content.slug$lang, content.sub_category_id, category.slug$lang FROM blog_category AS content LEFT JOIN blog_category AS category ON content.sub_category_id = category.id WHERE content.status='1' ORDER BY content.sort_order ASC");

        foreach($result as $row){
            $categoryList[] = [
                'id' => $row[0],
                'title' => $row[1],
                'slug' => $row[2],
                'sub_category' => $row[4],
            ];
        }
        return $categoryList;

    }
```

And in HTML:

```
    <?php foreach ($category as $categoryItem): ?>
        <h4><a href="/blog/<?php if ($categoryItem['sub_category']) echo $categoryItem['sub_category'] . '/'; ?><?php echo $categoryItem['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $categoryItem['title']; ?></a></h4>
        <p><?php echo $categoryItem['id']; ?></p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Please use the recursion method to get your need to fulfill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many different ways to do this, but I think the best would be to first load all categories into PHP from the database as long as there arent thousands and thousands of categories.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT category.id, category.parent_id, category.slug$lang FROM category");

// Populate $categories as an array of id => (slug, id, parent_id) items.
```

Then use a recursive php function to build a breadcrumb of categories.

```
function getBreadcrumb($categories, $categoryId) {

    $thisCat = $categories[$categoryId];

    if ($thisCat['parent_id'] != 0)
    {
       return array_merge(getBreadcrumb($categories, $thisCat['parent_id']), array($thisCat['slug']));
    }   
    else
    {
       return array($thisCat['slug']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I populated $categories as Array ( [id] => Array ( [id] => 1 [sub_category_id] => 0 [slug_en] => Title ) ) I trying to call function via foreach but get "Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' ". Can you tell how to properly call the function?

Comment: I'm not sure where you are going wrong without seeing the whole code. I edited the function slightly so you have to pass in the $categories array. Also, you need to populate the $categories array AND you also have to do your original looking up of the post data query as well. Paste it into a pastebin.com and I can have a look.

Comment: here is the code: https://pastebin.com/bed0r3ie I aswell tried to do this in another way(after ALSO: ), but currently cant get this work too, mysqli complain on max_user_connections D: Guess something wrong with it or indeed I'll need more connections per user.

Comment: Okay your code needs a LOT of improvement. You need to spend some more time going over programming fundamentals. I had to kinda guess what you're trying to do, and I wrote this: https://pastebin.com/7f9TKnvL . I split it into 3 functions - 1) Get a list of categories from the DB, 2) Given a category, create a list of all it's parents in order (breadcrumb). and 3) load Blog posts from your content table and calculate breadcrumbs for each post.

Comment: Yeah I trying my best to figure everything out, though your code is kinda complicated for me :) I did few changes in code to make your code work. But it works just as mine - without displaying full path of category. Just as site.com/sub-category/article or site.com/sub-category, without displaying parent

Comment: That was silly me. I wanted to use a part of your code to get just a list of categories. Didn't worked for me, but I managed to get it in a string alike. As I back to your code I modified a bit to fullfill my desires and it works just a should. Thanks a lot.